# Convexity of a scalar function

Tags: optimization, covariance

I'm looking into the following:

$ \min_A \|AC_iA^T - C_R\|_F^2$

where both $C_i$ and $C_R$ are symmetric matrices. They are the covariance matrices of some random variables. I wasn't sure how to find if the following function is convex.

Comment: the function is not convex in general, not even for scalars

Comment: How to show it though?

Comment: it includes the special case $(a^2 - 1)^2$, which is not convex.